Analogue of Bolzano–Weierstrass principle for ordered sets
Is it true that for a linearly ordered set $A$, completeness is equivalent to the fact that for any infinite subset $B$ of an interval (interval is the set of $x\in A$ such that $a \leq x \leq b$, for some $a,b \in A$, $a\leq b$), there exists a point $y\in A$ such that for any $c,d\in A$, $c<y<d$, there is a point $z\in B\cap\{x\in A :c <x<d\}\setminus \{y\}$.
The question came, when I was studying statements, that are equivalent to axiom of completeness in ordered fields. There is a proof that completeness implies Bolzano-Weierstrass principle, based on dividing the interval in half. But this proof cannot be applied to ordered sets. I would like to understand if, for them, a statement analogous to the Bolzano-Weierstrass principle would imply completeness. And vice versa.

For information on asking questions here, see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/

You tag "general-topology", so I am concerned that under the discrete topology, a (sub-)set is a union of one-point open sets, none of which contain a second point of $B$.  Your fact about $B$ seems to be defining "dense".

Your question is confusing, for instance, what does "except for this point itself mean"? Does it refer to the first point or to the second point? I guess, it would be much clearer, if you name the points, or, even better, ask your question using quantifiers. Moreover, I would expect that the point to exist, shall be contained in $B$?

@Ulli Sorry, I don't understand, what you mean. In ordered fields completeness and statement in the post are equivalent.

@Ulli for example, $x+1/2^k$, $x\in [0, 1]$ is appropriate irrational number, interval [0,1]. But I don't see, how it is connected to question about ordered sets

Ah yes, I think I got it now. $B$ is not the interval, but just an infinite set contained in a closed interval. Sorry, but at least your first formulation was so confusing, that I didn't see what it meant.

@Ulli Edited, is it still confusing?

It's clear now, thank you. Perhaps one suggestion: it would be easier to read, if you use different letters in the definition of "interval" and in the condition, but not $a,b$ in both places.

Just for clarification: Since you are talking about ordered fields, here completeness means that every non-empty subset bounded above has a supremum, i.e., the set need not have maximum or minimum.
Vice versa, if $A$ has a minimum or maximum, then the condition
is vacuously true (with $y = \text{min }A$ or $y = \text{max }A$, respectively).
Therefore, let us assume that $A$ has no minimum and no maximum.
Define $A$ is countably complete, if every
non-empty, countable subset bounded above has a supremum, and
every non-empty, countable subset bounded below has an infimum.
(In contrast to the general case, where the sup-condition implies the inf-condition, for the countable case we have to consider both cases.)
Then we have:

$A$ is countably complete, if and only if the above condition holds.

"$\Rightarrow$:"
Let $B$ be an infinite subset contained in a closed interval. Then B contains a strictly increasing or strictly decreasing sequence. W.l.o.g., let $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ be a strictly increasing sequence in $B$. Then there exists
$y = \text{sup} \{x_n: n \in \mathbb N\}$. It is easy to see that $y$ is as required.
"$\Leftarrow$:"
Let $T$ be a non-empty, countable subset of $A$, which is bounded above.
We have to show that $T$ has a supremum. W.l.o.g., we may assume that $T$ has no maximum. Hence, $T$ contains a cofinal, strictly increasing sequence
$(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$.
Since $T$ is bounded above, $B = \{x_n: n \in \mathbb N\}$ is contained in a closed interval.
Let $y$ be as in the condition.
$y$ is an upper bound of $B$:

Assume not, then there is a least $n \in \mathbb N$, such that
$y < x_n$.
 Case 1: $n = 1$.
Since $A$ has no minimum, there is an $a \in A, a < y$.
Hence, there is an $m$, such that $a < x_m < x_1$. Contradiction!
 Case 2: $n  > 1, y \neq x_{n-1}$. Then there is an $m$, such that $x_{n-1} < x_m < x_n$. Contradiction!
 Case 3: $n > 2, y = x_{n-1}$. Then there is an $m \neq n-1$, such that $x_{n-2} < x_m < x_n$. Contradiction!
 Case 4: $n = 2, y = x_1$. Argue as in case 1 and case 3 for a contradciton.
$y$ is the least upper of $B$:
 Assume not, then there is an upper bound $x$ of $B$, such that
$x < y$.
Since $A$ has no maximum, pick $c \in A, y < c$.
Then there is an $m \in \mathbb N$, such that
$x < x_m < c$. Contradiction.
Hence, $y$ is also the supremum of $T$.
The inf-case is analogously.
$\square$
It follows that each completely linearly ordered set $A$ fullfills the condition. But not vice versa:
Let $A_1 = \{z \in \mathbb Z: z < 0\} \cup \omega_1$, linearly orderded in the obvious way.
(The $\mathbb Z$ part is just added to ensure that the final set has no minimum.)
Let $A_2$ be a disjoint copy of $A_1$, reversely ordered.

$A = A_1 \cup A_2$, linearly ordered by extending the orders of $A_1$ and $A_2$, and $x_1 < x_2$ for all $x_1 \in A_1, x_2 \in A_2$.
(The order on $A$ is quite simple, it's just tedious to describe it.)
Then $A$ is countably complete, but not complete, since $A_1$ has no supremum.

Can you please write with more details, what you mean by  "if A
has a minimum or maximum, then the condition is vacuously true (with y=min A
or y=max A respectively)"?

Let $y = \text{min} (A)$. Then $y$ fullfills the condition for any set $B$, since there is no $c \in A$ such that $c < y$.
